# Primefaces calendar not firing dateSelect

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to get a value from my calendar via ajax.

xhtml portion:

```
<p:calendar
    id="newSimFrom"
    value="#{SimModel.from}" <!-- this works -->
    showOn="button"
    mask="true"
    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
>                       
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this" update="newSimUnt" listener="#{SimController.simFromChanged()}" />
</p:calendar>
```

controller:

```
public void simFromChanged(SelectEvent se) {
    log.info("called");
    log.info(""+se.getObject()); 
    //this is temporary till I can figure out what's even going on
}
```

But I get nothing, no event seems to be fired.
I've also tried `event="change"` as well as `event="select"` and `process="@this"` (latter as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295586)

Also, I've tried to put the listener on with and without the parenthesises, didn't seem to make any differences.

The calendar is inside a form tag. (Kinda, there's 2 layers if `<div>` above, does that make a difference?) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213127/7591918)

Any ideas where I should go to for debugging what's going on? I'm relatively new to Primefaces and JSF as a whole, my IDE's console and my browser console don't give me any errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Apparently, my problem was with how Spring internally addresses classes, or rather how the automatic name generation works, as I did not explicitly name the bean.

```
listener="#{SimController.newSimFromChanged}"
```

was changed to

```
listener="#{simController.newSimFromChanged}"
```

(note the lowercase s)

And now it works.

This is pretty unintuitive (IMO), and I'm not sure this is universally applicable but I'm going to leave this here if someone else ever has the same problem. Do note that this also does not apply if your class starts with multiple uppercase letters, if I had named my class `SIMController` it would have worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

The method in your listener isn't spelled correctly. You forgot the "new".

If you want to get the event don't use parentheses.

The event you get is a DateSelectEvent, so this should work:

xhtml:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this" update="newSimUnt" listener="#{SimController.newSimFromChanged}" />
```

controller:

```
public void newSimFromChanged(DateSelectEvent se) {
    log.info("called");
    log.info("" + se.getDate()); 
    //this is temporary till I can figure out what's even going on
}
```

If that doesn't work the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, no, let me fix that. It's spelled correctly in my actual code, I cut it down to make it more readable for StackOverflow. Edit: By cut it down, I don't mean I omitted anything, I just changed the function names.

Answer (score 0):

Wep0n, try these examples:

```
<p:calendar id="newSimFrom" value="#{SimModel.from}"
            showOn="button" mask="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="newSimUnt" 
                    listener="#{SimController.simFromSelected}" />

            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="newSimUnt" 
                    listener="#{SimController.simFromChanged}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

And inside your managedBean SimController:

```
public void simFromSelected(DateSelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("DateSelectEvent " + event.getDate());
}

public void simFromChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws MWSException {
    System.out.println("AjaxBehaviorEvent " + event.getDate());
}
```

Comment: DateSelectEvent is deprecated and no longer recognized/included in the version of Primefaces I'm using. I got my code mostly right except for what I said in my own answer. Thanks though, definitely going to look into AjaxBehaviourEvent for future reference, as well.